# subprocess.Popen from python errors when I try run. Work fine in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm very new to Python and searching answers on Stack, So if it is a noob mistake, I beg forgiveness and if the answer exist somewhere send me on my way.

Finished 1 small course (on youtube) of Python and I have a batch file I want to turn into Python as a first project.
Basically the batch file opens all the apps I need when I'm at the office.

I've gotten to writing this much of my first project. Edited pieces of the code for obvious reasons.

```
import subprocess
keys = []
open_now = ""
count = 0
programs_to_run = {'Chrome': r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
                   'Outlook': r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.exe'}

# This line puts the keys in dictionary in a usable list
for key in programs_to_run.keys():
    # print(key)
    keys.append(key)

for program in programs_to_run:
    open_now = "programs_to_run.get(programs_to_run.get(keys[count]))"
    subprocess.Popen(open_now)
    print(f'Opening {keys[count]}!')
    # print(programs_to_run.get(keys[count]))
    count += 1

print("*****************************************************************")
print("All applications opened fine.")
print("*****************************************************************")

input('Press ENTER to exit')

quit()
```

I've tested the subprocess.Popen('Full Path') in Command prompt and it worked just fine.
Being a noob I've tested every section the subprocess being print and it worked fine.

When I run the above code as is I get the following. Line for subprocess would have changed due to my dictionary being smaller (Total of 8 Applications that I want to open)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/OneDrive - Company/Python_Projects/WorkSetup/WorkSetup.py", line 28, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(programs_to_run.get(programs_to_run.get(keys[count])))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1247, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 549, in list2cmdline
    for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any and all help welcome.

I'm still learning code so please keep the Language to Total noob level.

End Goal; Have a script/ Executable that starts with the PCs,  checks if i'm in the office (if local domain is Reachable), Not sure how to accomplish this step for now. Will Research closer to the time.
If yes open all app apps, If not Only open 2.

Comment: `"programs_to_run.get(programs_to_run.get(keys[count]))"` is Python code. How would `cmd` ever successfully interpret it?

Comment: If you want to _execute_ that code, and put the _result_ of executing it in `open_now`, then you need to take off the quotes around it.

Comment: ...whereas if you _take off_ the quotes, then I strongly suggest that you inspect the returned value before passing it to `Popen` and make sure it's actually something that's sensible and in line with what you expect. As it's currently given, this is not a problem with `subprocess`, but a problem with the code generating the argument to `subprocess`; you could factor all the `subprocess`-related parts out and still have a question (and it would be a better -- tighter, narrower, more specific -- question).

Comment: I went back following your expert eyes, Changing subprocess to print and it wasn't pulling correctly. Removed open_now all together and changed subprocess.Popen(programs_to_run.get(programs_to_run.get(keys[count]))) to subprocess.Popen(programs_to_run.get(keys[count]))
and that worked. Thank you for bearing with me

Comment: Thanks for the advise I'll work on making questions simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import subprocess

programs_to_run = {'Chrome': r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
                   'Outlook': r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.exe'}

for program in programs_to_run:
    subprocess.Popen([], executable = programs_to_run[program])
    print(f'Opening {program}!')

print("*****************************************************************")
print("All applications opened fine.")
print("*****************************************************************")

input('Press ENTER to exit')

quit()
```